# TI Basic how to do store value in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, store, default-value, ti-basic

I'm trying to write a program in notepad++ the language is TI Basic.

On a TI 83 or 84 calculator when programming you can store a value to a letter by using the `STO>` button. In the code `STO>` is represented by ex: `2+2=4-->x`. How would I write that in notepad++.

EDIT: To clarify my question i'm writing a program in TI-Basic language within Notepad++. I would like to do a simple equation and have the result stored to "x". The part im struggling with how would I write it? I know how to do it within the calculator itself. I would use the `STO>` key. For example this is how I would write it in the calculator `2+2=4 STO>X` but, the actual code would look like `2+2=4-->X`. I cant exactly write --> within an editor. Reason being it would give me a syntex error when I run it.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Notepad++ is an editor, it can be used to write programs in (as far as I know) any programming language. Perhaps you should be asking "How can I write that in TI Basic?" Additionally, please show any code that you have tried already and explain why that did not do what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, when you type things on a calculator, they are really just 1 or 2 byte tokens representing that symbol or command. This means you cant just write plaintext and poof it on to a calculator and expect it to work. As said before TI Program Editor is a good one, but TokenIDE in my opinion is better because it has syntax highlighting and will recognize things like -> without having to type the unicode arrow like in Ti Program Editor. There are also a few online ones if you do some research, but thats up to you. Once you build a program in one of these editors, you simply get it to your calculator with the normal TI Connect software, and run it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

lemondrop is right, you'll need a special program editor to make TI programs on your PC.

I've used [TI Connect CE](https://education.ti.com/en/software/details/en/CA9C74CAD02440A69FDC7189D7E1B6C2/swticonnectcesoftware) before, and I think it'll work well for your purposes. There are others out there though.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* try this -> or this →, but I'm not sure if it would work. *I haven't tried it on my calculator before.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29861455)